Discord x GitHub webhook integrated via Vercel CICD on Expressjs+TypeScript App
so the thing is, I've CICD integrated on vercel. It's a Node, Express, GraphQL and MongoDB app built on TypeScript. GitHub has app installed vercel on the repository and whenever there's a new commit on defined branch, it runs the pipeline and deploy the app as a serverless function. after deployment vercel triggers the GitHub to update the deployment section on repository and so does the GitHub. Note that, there is no workflow written for it.
Next then I've a discord webhook setup on the repo, it was supposed to trigger on deployment. But it is not. And when I change the webhook configuration on GitHub webhook to Send me everything it only sends the 'commit' update on discord and not the deployment.
What's the solution for this to get the deployment update on Discord server. How can I monitor the post-deployment event on GitHub so that it reflects the changes to my Discord. Or what you guys suggest. Please note that to maximum extend we don'that want to disturb vercel auto deployment but exception is there. And it's a development/testing environment. SS added for clarity
